# How to deal with in multi components to fetch data in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

In my Vue.js project, I have many components, in some of them, those component will all use a fetched data list, called it `server_list`.

I don't want to fetch it in every component who used it.

so, how can I optimize this?

only in one place to fetch it?

such as, In `component_foo`, I will invoke `fetch_server_list()`, in `component_bar`, I will invoke `fetch_server_list()` too.

How can I deal with in multi places to fetch server list data?

What's your best way to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that.

**[Props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#ad)**

Props lets you pass data to child component.

**[Provide/Inject](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#provide-inject)**

Providers lets you pass data nested, more than one level.

**[Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/)**

Vuex stores lets you cache your data in $store object to use later, wherever you want.

Comment: Can you give a detail example of Vuex? I mean my data is fetched from API.

Comment: @sof-03 you can check guide of vuex.